# Changing button image on different button tag in Xcode

Tags: ios, keyboard, tags, uiimage

I'm creating a custom keyboard for iOS and having a hard time figuring out how to change UIImage of the "shift" key using tags. When the user selects the shift key I'm using:

```
if( btn.tag == 100 ) {
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"shift_en.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    .......
}
```

Where "btn" is defined as:

```
func btnPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        var btn = sender as UIButton
        ........
```

Everything works fine until the user hits a character key and I'd like to "disable" the shift key and change the shift image again. However, since the new "btn" now represents the character key and the tag is changed to the new character tag, how do I change the previous tag UIImage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the *UIButton* objects present in the current view. e.g. if all your buttons are added to `self.view`, then iterate like

> for tempBtn in self.view.subviews

then you can check if individual *tempBtn* has the same tag as of the *shift* button, then you can set the image.

> if (tempBtn.tag == 100)
>
> ```
>    tempBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"shift_en.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
> ```